# Override Angular Directive link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have limited knowledge of Angular so please bear with me. I am in a situation where I can only modify one js file which is included BEFORE all of the Angular stuff. There is a directive that is causing a problem, yet I can not modify it directly. So I've tried to override it by adding the snippet below in a document ready block:

```
app.directive('selectionChange', function($rootScope){
   return {
      priority: 1,
      terminal: true,
      link: function(scope, el, attr) {
         console.log('works');
      };
   };
});
```

I can see this directive added to the end of the invokeQueue, but it is never executed. How do I get this attached? Thanks!

UPDATE:

Sorry, let me try to clarify. Problem is, the original directive continues to fire, but the newly attached one does not (tested by using console.log and alert). The markup is something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script src="[the file I can modify].js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="directives.js"></script> // here is where the existing selectionChange directive is defined
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post any markup for this? It should not work only if the element is not loaded.

Comment: Can you please also indicate how you are using the directive in markup?

Comment: Something is fishy when people start asking how to make changes because they "can't" edit other files in their project, especially when they claim those files are "broken".  If you can't fix it, and you aren't able to have the person who wrote it fix it either, then why is it even included in the first place, if it's "broken"?

Comment: I can understand that sentiment as my details are sparse, but to clarify, I said it is causing a problem, not broken. The problem being that I need to dynamically insert new select elements into the DOM and that is a problem for this directive because it doesn't expect these extra selects. I can only say that in a big company, there are separate groups, often with heavy workloads. Going through "regular channels" to get something changed for you can take weeks, if not months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WnFmTsYacMYB1ysspQJe?p=preview)

```
$(function () {
  var app = angular.module('app');

  app.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('badDirective', function ($delegate) {
      var badDirective = $delegate[0];

      var link = function (scope, element) {
        element.text('good');
      }

      var originalCompile = badDirective.compile || function () {};
      badDirective.compile = function () {
        originalCompile.apply(badDirective, arguments);

        // compile returns link fn, directive 'link' property will be ignored anyway
        return link;
      }

      return $delegate;
    });    
  });
})
```

Doing it on 'ready' state (e.g. jQuery `ready` implementation) is the right thing. This way the code will be launched before the bootstrapping process (it will be queued on 'ready' via `ng-app` as soon as angular.js is loaded).

`bad` directive is just `badDirective` service internally which contains an array of DDO (because there can be several directives with the same name). And it can be decorated, as any other service.

Link function can be defined with either `link` or `compile` (it can return link) DDO properties. The second overrides the first, so always stick to `compile` when decorating directives.

Comment: Thanks estus! You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

In the file you can modify create a script tag with a (reference/definition) to your new directive and place that tag at the bottom of the body right after the troubled directive definition. By being the last one defined you'll ensure that is your directive the one rendered.